# avoid repetition in a Java array

Tags: java, arrays, duplicates

I'm trying to get my code to not only search if a char is present in an array, but also if it is present next to one another. So, if the input is hannah, the output should be hanah. It should only remove a char if it is next to the same char.

```
import java.util.*;   

public class test {   
    
  static void removeDuplicate(char str[], int length) {   
        
      int index = 0; 
  
      for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {   
             
          int j;   
          for (j = 0; j < i; j++) {   
              if (str[i] == str[j])   
              {   
                  break;
              }   
          }   
    
          if (j == i)    
          {     
              str[index++] = str[i];   
          }   
      } 
      System.out.println(String.valueOf(Arrays.copyOf(str, index)));   
  }   
  
 
  public static void main(String[] args)   {   
      String info = "hannahmontana";  
      char str[] = info.toCharArray();  
      int len = str.length;   
      removeDuplicate(str, len);   
  }   
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Do any of [these search results](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjava%5D+remove+duplicates) answer the question? Please [try to do research](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592) before asking.

Comment: Instead of `String.valueOf(Arrays.copyOf(str, index))` you can use `new String(str, 0, index)` and save one copy operating during the string concatenation.

Answer (score 2):

You can also try RegExp. Maybe not so fast, but I consider it simpler and more readable.

```java
static String removeDuplicate(char[] chars, int ignored) {
    return new String(chars).replaceAll("(.)\\1+", "$1")
}
```

Comment: Actually, this will be faster than all other answers here (for non-trivial string sizes). Only the OP’s original approach might be slightly faster, once all issues are fixed.

Answer (score 0):

This my solution

```
static String removeDuplicate(char str[], int length) {
    if (length == 0) return "";
    List<Character> list = new ArrayList<>();
    list.add(str[0]);
    for (int i = 1; i < length; i++) {
        if (list.get(list.size() - 1) != str[i]) {
            list.add(str[i]);
        }
    }
    return list.stream()
            .map(Object::toString)
            .collect(Collectors.joining());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do a ***recursive*** call here:

```
import java.util.*;   

public class test {   
    
  static String removeDuplicate(String input) {   
        
     if(input.length()<=1)
            return input;
        if(input.charAt(0)==input.charAt(1))
            return removeDuplicate(input.substring(1));
        else
            return input.charAt(0) + removeDuplicate(input.substring(1));
  }   
  
 
  public static void main(String[] args)   {   
      String info = "hannahmontana";  
      System.out.println(removeDuplicate(info));
  }   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all the great answers! It turns out the solution was really simple. I just needed to change `str[j]` to `str[i-1]`.